# Can I reset shared_ptr without deleting object so that weak_ptr loses a reference to it

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I'd like to reset a `shared_ptr` without deleting its object and let `weak_ptr` of it loses a reference to it. However, `shared_ptr` doesn't have release() member function for reasons, so I can't directly do it. The easiest solution for this is just to call `weak_ptr`'s reset() but the class which owns the `shared_ptr` and wants to release it doesn't know which class has `weak_ptr` of it. How can that be achieved in this case?

I understand why `shared_ptr` doesn't have release function but `unique_ptr`. In my case, only one instance owns a pointer, but `shared_ptr` can be owned by multiple instances and releasing doesn't make sense then. But if `shared_ptr` doesn't have that function, how can I cut connections to `weak_ptr` without deleting the object?

```
shared_ptr<int> A = make_shared<int>(100);
weak_ptr<int> B = A;

// I want something like this! but shared_ptr doesn't have release function..
int* releasedData = A.release();
A.reset(releasedData);

if (shared_ptr<int> C = B.lock)
{
    // B already lost a reference, so it should never reach here
}
```

### Background

A shared pointer of a class which stores a pointer of a large array is shared with other classes. The shared pointer is passed as a weak pointer to those, and the owner class of the shared pointer doesn't know about those classes. Multiple instances of the owner class are activated and deactivated at runtime. Because initializing cost of the instance is high, I use object pool pattern: I reuse those instances instead of creating/deleting every time I use it. The problem here is that when an instance of the owner class is deactivated, it should be tread as removed(although it still holds the data), and thus other classes which has a weak reference to the data should lose the reference. Resetting a shared pointer makes it possible, but I don't want to do it because the data is large.

I can make a manager class to keep track of which weak pointer refers to which shared pointer, but I wonder if this can be solved by something else.

Comment: This won't work with `shared_ptr`'s created with `make_shared` because `make_shared` combines the `int` and the control block into a single allocation. They are inseparable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` are made to model the concept of [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). When you use a `std::shared_ptr`, you already made the decision that it owns the resource, and that it should release the resource on destruction. The clunkiness you face is due to a rebellion against RAII: you want `std::shared_ptr` to own the resource but sometimes not really.

The solution is to reframe your object pool as an allocator. Suppose you have

```
struct obj_t { /* ... */ };

struct pool_t {
    obj_t* acquire();      // get an object from the pool
    void release(obj_t*);  // return the object to the pool
    // ...
};
```

Then your `std::shared_ptr` will look like

```
auto d = [&pool](auto p){ pool.release(p); };
std::shared_ptr<obj_t> obj{pool.acquire(), d};
```

Notably, the resource acquisition *always* gets paired with its destruction.
Under this model your problem doesn't exist

```
std::weak_ptr<obj_t> b = obj;
obj = nullptr;  // or let obj get destroyed in any other way

if(auto c = b.lock())
    // doesn't happen
```

Comment: `d` can be stored in `pool_t`, can't it? And also a `make_shared` like function added to the pool?

Comment: @Sebastian `d` can be made to be a member function, e.g. `auto d = pool.get_deleter();`. You can also have a `make_shared` like function sure. Whether you want your object pool to encompass them is a design choice.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a `shared_ptr` with custom deleter that would prevent the object from being destroyed:

```cpp
shared_ptr<int> A = shared_ptr<int>(new int(100), [](int*){});
weak_ptr<int> B = A;

// Save the pointer that you otherwise would lose:
int* releasedData = A.get();
A = shared_ptr<int>(releasedData, [](int*){});;

if (shared_ptr<int> C = B.lock())
{
    // B already lost a reference, so it should never reach here
}
```

But don't forget to delete the object by any other means. For example:

```cpp
shared_ptr<int> realOwner(new int(100));

shared_ptr<int> A = shared_ptr<int>(realOwner.get(), [](int*){});
weak_ptr<int> B = A;
```